# Eclipse is not importing com.google.api.client. imports?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, google-calendar-api

I am trying to implement Google's calendar API into my spring boot project in eclipse. I am following this [Java tutorial from the Google Developers' website](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java)

I am on step 3 where I am to copy in code, however there are errors under all of the Google API imports:

[image]

The error I get:

> The import com.google cannot be resolved

The Gradle file leading to the error:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I added the following to the Pom file and it removed almost all of the import errors:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev224-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, the following two imports still have errors:

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
```

Comment: Did you add the required dependencies to your gradle file? Can you post it please? Did you also do a full rebuild of the project?

Comment: @BackSlash I edited the question there and added in a snip of the gradle file! Do you think I need to add anything to the pom file? I don't understand what you mean by a full rebuild of the project.

Comment: A pom? Does eclipse think this is a maven project or a gradle project?

Comment: @Jill That could be the issue - A gradle project doesn't have a pom, as it's a Maven file.

Comment: This is a maven project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use both gradle and maven together. Use either `gradle` or `pom`.

Remove the gradle build file and add the dependencies in the pom.xml as you mentioned.

Then go to `maven ==> Update Project`

And that should download the dependencies and fix the errors.

Comment: I removed the gradle build file and added the dependencies to the pom and it fixed the errors however then the project wouldn't run so i decided to ditch this tutorial since it uses gradle.

Comment: @Jill If this helped can you please mark the answer as accepted. And what error did it throw?

Comment: Technically your answer did solve the question! I don't remember the error because I just removed all code related to that tutorial and I'm now looking for a new way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add all the dependencies to the POM file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
    <version>v3-rev305-1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But op is using `gradle` and not `maven`.

Comment: Check the comments, OP says it is a maven project.

Answer (score -1):

I think issue here is the way eclipse handle gradle project

Use Eclipse Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)

install https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egradle-ide#group-details

re import your project as gradle project

==
delete pom.xml, I think eclipse confuses between gradle project vs maven project